# MySQL Error 1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I am doing a assessment and one of the tasks requests us to

> Create and populate a third table called entries again using query scripts. This table should contain foreign keys to allow sensible links to be made with the other two tables, together with the dates of each exam

The two tables mentioned in the request were created using these

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subjects(
subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
subject_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
level_of_entry VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
exam_board VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (subject_id));
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS students(
student_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
middle_name VARCHAR(20),
last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
password CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
reg_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
UNIQUE (email));
```

To create the Entries Table I am using this script;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(
subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
subject_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
level_of_entry VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
exam_board VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (date_of_exam),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_name) REFERENCES subjects(subject_name)
);
```

However Like mentioned above , I am getting "ERROR 1215 (HY000) : Cannot add foreign key constraint.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Error on which table script ?

Comment: Error on the Entries Table script (The Last Script on the Question)

Comment: I am trying to get the two foreign keys from the tables students and entries to link with the entries table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although Tim's answer is correct but I would suggest you to not have subject_name column in Entries table at all . You can always get it from subjects table . 
But still if you want to keep subjects_name column in Entries table and want to add a FOREIGN key constraint on subjects_name column then either declare subjects_name as unique column in subjects table

```
alter table `subjects` add unique (`subject_name`);
```

or create an index on subjects_name column in subjects table.

```
alter table `subjects` add index subject_name_index(`subject_name`);
```

then  create `Entries` table .

Answer (score 0):

This is the line which is causing problems:

```
FOREIGN KEY (subject_name) REFERENCES subjects(subject_name)
```

The reason it is causing problems is because `subject_name` is not a primary key column in the `subjects` table.  There are a number of ways to resolve this.  The approach I might use would be to just drop this bad foreign key definition, i.e. use this definition for `entries`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(
    subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    subject_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    level_of_entry VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    exam_board VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (date_of_exam),
    FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id)
)
```

If you want to ensure that a given `subject_id` will always be associated with a unique `subject_name` in the `subjects` table, you can do that by making the `subject_name` column unique:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS subjects (
    subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    subject_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    level_of_entry VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    exam_board VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (subject_id)
    UNIQUE KEY u_key (subject_name)
)
```

Then, a given `subject_name` can only be associated with at most one `subject_id`.

Answer (score 0):

First, What is purpose of your entries table ?
subjects and entries look not difference

Second, never use DATETIME as primary key

Try this query :

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(
entrie_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
subject_id INT NOT NULL,
student_id INT NOT NULL,
date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (entrie_id),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id)
);
```

Comment: This has not worked and I am getting the same error.